# How to set header content-tye "text/xml;charset=utf-8" soap request

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap

The request I sent gets an error this way. "Problems creating SAAJ object model"

Does anyone have an idea?

```
{
XYZEndpointClient client = new XYZEndpointClient();
XYZService.ServiceInput sorguServiceInput = new XYZService.sorguServiceInput();
string wso2Url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["url"];

Uri uri = new Uri(wso2Url);
AddressHeader addressHeader = AddressHeader.CreateAddressHeader("Content-Type", wso2Url,"text/xml;charset=utf-8");

client.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(uri, addressHeader);
sorguServiceInput.ID = 1;
sorguServiceInput.Name = "Name";
var response= client.sorgula(sorguServiceInput);
}
```

Comment: Does your `client` have an `Open` method or something like that?